# How do I add args to custom i18n messages in grails?

Tags: grails

I have an object which I declared as "unique:true" and then I created a custom message in message.properties in grails. It appears correctly, but I don't know how to pass arguments to it. Is it even possible?

```
net.mypackage.MyObject.myField.unique = The Object {0} already belongs to the Object Group {1}.
```

I am aware that I can pass args via "g:message" but in this case I am rendering my errors via this snippet:

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${object}">
                        <ul class="errors no-margin" role="alert">
                            <g:eachError bean="${object}" var="error">
                            <li <g:if test="${error in org.springframework.validation.FieldError}">data-field-id="${error.field}"</g:if>><g:message error="${error}"/></li>
                            </g:eachError>
                        </ul>
                    </g:hasErrors>
```

I can probably hack it like say do an if-else to determine if the error was a "unique constraint" error then pass the values, but other than that I don't have any idea. Most of the custom message examples I see on the internet are related to custom validators. I tried.. But I dont want to resort to that just yet... Any opinions on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Grails documentation (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/i18n.html):

```
<g:message code="my.localized.content" args="${ ['Juan', 'lunes'] }" />
```

Comment: yeah I know about that.. But like I said, I'm generating the errors via g:eachError (see 2nd snippet above)... How do I insert the args from there?

Comment: The class org.springframework.validation.FieldError has method `getArguments()`, which returns `Object[]`, so you can use it. In my opinion, you are already doing a slightly complicated logic in the template, which should not be there. It would be better to implement a custom tag, which is also reusable.

Comment: Thanks. If there is getArguments() then I should be able to setArguments() or something like that...Right? Thanks. Currently, I set a custom tag for it, but the client needed to know where the current object belongs to so that they are aware of where it lies. I thought I'd be stuck.. :D OMG! Thanks so much for saving my butt! <3

Comment: Glad to help :-) Your second SO issue is still active? I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183911/grails-creates-the-table-in-mysql-but-my-form-is-not-saving-no-errors-too

Comment: No. I already found the solution for that one. It just so happen that I forgot to update.

Comment: Well, I have few abandoned answers by questions, which has been created by users with low score ... looks like 1 time user, so it was a vaste of time :-( Luckily, not by you :-)